# Keyboard retraining helper apps

Tags: windows, accessibility, keyboard-listener

Since breaking my wrist a couple of years ago I have gained a couple of systematic keyboarding skills fails.

Mainly I think it is that my hand is fractionally slower than it used to be, and when doing certain 2-handed shift key sequences that are heavily ingrained I am releasing the shift key before my bad hand has actually hit the key I want to shift.

I had hoped it would come back naturally, but no. And practicing the sequences in isolation hasn't helped me either.

I'm thinking there might be some keyboard intercept software out there that could beep/flash, or whatever, if it detects in quick succession (or something I could modify0 (there we go again!):

shift+unshift+letter

"(0" (i.e. shift+9+unshift+0)

And to do that while I get on with my job...

Clarification: My aim is to train myself to wait the correct additional moment before releasing shift - I'm not trying to fix the keyboard to wait for me, just get some instant feedback.

Anyone seen something at all like this, or anything that could be hacked to help?

Comment: You might want to look into the all hated sticky keys and use those instead, might be easier to just click it once then click whatever you want rather than looking for software that could flag keyboard inputs incorrectly

Comment: Hmm... I don't really want to give up on typing properly. Mostly I get my shift keying correct,. I just want to retrain myself to get the timing right.